# Redirecting www to non-www works for main pages, doesn't work for folders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-redirect

I use such redirect code in `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}$1 [C]
RewriteRule ^www\.(.*)$ http://$1 [L,R=301]
```

When I type: `www.domain.com/file.php` it works ok forwarding to `domain.com/file.php`

When I type: `www.domain.com/folder/folder2` I'm redirected to: `domain.comfolder/folder2` (with no slash)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why that's happening, but those rules don't work at all when I put them in my htaccess file in a vanilla apache 2.2 install. Since it looks like all you're doing is redirecting a **www.domain.com** request to a **domain.com** request, you could just do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Instead of chaining rules together and rewriting the host into the URI-path.